# Connect to SOAP Web Services from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, html, soap

I am very new to Soap web services and HTML5 i want develop App using html5 and soap webservices i have soap web-services wsdl and lo-gin credential how can i connect that services from html5 app.please send any useful links or samples  to me so that i can try .

Thanks in Advance is there any third party frame work to connect Soap Web-services .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP is an XML based protocol. Though Javascript can in theory read and consume SOAP replies, in practice this is not possible due to browser security limitations and such to keep Internet as a sane place.

What you want to do is to create an middlware which translates your HTML5 client-side AJAX requests to SOAP requests on the server and then returns results as a translated JSON.

SOAP traffic is better to be handled server-to-server instead of directly from browser-to-server. Thus, the question is what kind of server resources you have to create and translate SOAP requests.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a scripting language. You can't connect to SOAP with that.
Look into PHP which has a SOAP class and then use that to generate the HTML.