# How to call the .net webservice with JQuery mobile framework?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

In my application, i need to call .NET Web Service which is return XML data. How to call Web Service with JQuery Mobile and how to display response. Guide me your possible ways.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381367/connect-to-soap-web-services-from-javascript/12409098#12409098

Comment: This question is too open-ended.  It's perfectly possible to retrieve data from a webservice using Javascript and using JQueryMobile doesn't change how you do it at all. Have a look at the AJAX methods on Jquery - $.get, $.ajax, $.getJSON